# Neo4j fulltext index is not created from apoc.conf

Tags: neo4j, full-text-search, neo4j-apoc

I have a custom neo4j docker image based on neo4j:4.4.
On it's startup, I need to execute a few cypher statements, which includes a creation of fulltext index. I am doing it using *apoc.conf* file:

```
apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=false
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
apoc.initializer.neo4j.0=CALL apoc.cypher.runSchemaFile("file:////var/lib/neo4j/db_init/create_regular_indexes.cypher")
apoc.initializer.neo4j.1=CALL apoc.cypher.runSchemaFile("file:////var/lib/neo4j/db_init/create_fulltext_indexes.cypher")
```

The *create_fulltext_indexes.cypher* file has the following content:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX CustomerIndex IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:Customer) ON EACH [n.name];
```

When I start the docker container, I see in the logs that the *create_fulltext_indexes.cypher* is executed, no errors are shown, but the *CustomerIndex* is not created. The indexes from *create_regular_indexes.cypher* are created normally.

Also, if I try to run the following command in the container:

```
cypher-shell -u user -p password "CALL apoc.cypher.runSchemaFile(\"file:////var/lib/neo4j/db_init/create_fulltext_indexes.cypher\")"
```

The *CustomerIndex* is not created, but when I am running the cypher statement in the neo4j browser, it works fine.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX CustomerIndex IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:Customer) ON EACH [n.name];
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would try to combine both of them in a single file

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in neo4j, GitHub issue created:
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/2395